# HTML2FO always uses Arial font in BI Publisher

Tags: bi-publisher

I'm trying to do a HTML conversion in my report(RTF) and it works but expected output change my font 'Times New Roman' to Arial. I believe, I changed my default font to Times New Roman even in xdo.config but still HTML2FO makes it Arial.
Other sections of the document has Times New Roman.

XML:

```
<TEST><p><b><i>This is a test paragraph</b></i>. This is without bold
and italic</p><p><b><i>This is another test paragraph</b></i>. This is
without bold and italic</p><TEST>
```

BIP Code:

```
<?HTML2FO:TEST?>
```

Could anyone please help me in getting this right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem too.  The way I got around this is to change the XML output:

```
<TEST><div style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:10px;"><p><b><i>This is a test paragraph</b></i>. This is without bold
and italic</p><p><b><i>This is another test paragraph</b></i>. This is
without bold and italic</p></div><TEST>
```